# Call to undefined method MessageBag::getBag()

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Inside a blade `@include` partial I have a form with a comment field. As soon as I add this bit of blade code for the validation error to the partial I get an error:

```
@error('body_comment')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

Error message:
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::getBag()`

More info, on how the view is rendered:

```
<div class="row trailer-xs">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
<textarea id="body_comment" type="text" class="form__input" name="body_comment" required
  autocomplete="body_comment">
</textarea>
<?php $__errorArgs = ['body_comment'];
$__bag = $errors->getBag($__errorArgs[1] ?? 'default');
if ($__bag->has($__errorArgs[0])) :
if (isset($message)) { $__messageOriginal = $message; }
$message = $__bag->first($__errorArgs[0]); ?>
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
<strong><?php echo e($message); ?></strong>
</span>
<?php unset($message);
if (isset($__messageOriginal)) { $message = $__messageOriginal; }
endif;
unset($__errorArgs, $__bag); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

I embed the form like this:

```
<section class="trailer-xs-x2" id="comment-form">
    @include('forms/comments/form-create-edit', [
        'method' => 'post',
        'route' => route('comments.store'),
        'submit' => __('Save comment'),
        'associateId' => $ticket->id,
    ])
</section>
```

Please help. Maybe I need to pass some error variable to the partial? I already tried passing a `$errors` to the partial. That didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. Apparently when you return a view() with the `withErrors($messages)` method but the `$messages` `MessageBag` provider is empty, it generates this error.

So for me the solution was to check if there is an error message in my MessageBag. If not just return the view without the `withErrors()` method.